# In spring One To Many entity relationship is not fetching data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have simple scenario where there is relation between **User** and **Skill**,
means one user many skills, so I tried with:

#### User

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;     
    private String name;    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Skill> skills;

}
```

#### Skill

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Skill {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;        
    private String skillTitle;      
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

}
```

#### UserRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

#### SkillRepository

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "skills", path = "skills")
public interface SkillRepository extends CrudRepository<Skill, Long>{
    
}
```

with all above I'm able to get response at for example url `http://localhost:8085/users/1`

```
{
    "name": "Root",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/users/1"
        },
        "user": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/users/1"
        },
        "skills": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/users/1/skills"
        }
    }
}
```

not the issue is I'm not figuring out why list of skills is not fetched, why only this is fetched

```
"skills": {
   "href": "http://localhost:8085/users/1/skills"
}
```

not a full list of skills related to `user/1`.

### UPDATE

Added projection as suggested:
UserProjection.java

```
@Projection(name = "inlineData", types=User.class)
public interface UserProjection {
    String getName();
    List<Skill> getSkills();
}
```

UserRepository.java is

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "users", path = "users", excerptProjection = UserProjection.class)
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

response is:

```
{
    "name": "Root",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/users/1"
        },
        "user": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/users/1{?projection}",
            "templated": true
        },
        "skills": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8085/users/1/skills"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the code where you are using findByUserId() function to produce this response?

Comment: isn't this what HATEOAS is about? you can see the user's skills if you click on the link.

Comment: @CholNhial that link shows nothing when clicked...

Comment: Also in API request, you are sending user1 but you are posting response for user3.

Comment: In the second example the name of the method is `findByUserId` but you are passing a `skillId` as a parameter. Is it ok?

Comment: @oxy_js user 3 may be a typo, and `findByUserId()` function is just declared not used yet any where

Comment: try `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)` I'm sure fetch is eager by default.

Comment: @oxy_js pardon me for that because there is a lot of code so I was just trying to provide code according to the contex of question..

Comment: @CholNhial same result, not fetching list of skills

Comment: turn on your Hibernate SQL logs and see what's up. `spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true` In `properties` file. Then watch the logs and see which query is generated when clicking on links

Comment: @CholNhial see the update

Comment: @ArshadAli, you might want to checkout `@Projection`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094635/spring-not-loading-data-even-with-fetchtype-eager-set.

Comment: @CholNhial never succeeded...

Comment: @CholNhial see latest edit

Comment: Projetcion is what you want. Are you actually requesting the projection i.e. calling url: `.../users/1?projection=inlineData`

Comment: *that link shows nothing when clicked.* What do you mean it shows nothing? It must show something...

Comment: @AlanHay I mean to say that returns as `"_embedded": {
        "skills": []
    }`

Comment: guys you can see this link https://rest-work.herokuapp.com/users

Answer (score 0):

The response is correct, it works as intended. `@RepositoryRestResource` follows [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)  principles. [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/) explains it as follows:

> 5.1.3. Resource Discoverability
>
> A core principle of HATEOAS is that resources should be discoverable
>   through the publication of links that point to the available
>   resources ...
>
> By issuing a request to the root URL ... the client can extract, from
>   the returned JSON object, a set of links that represent the next level
>   of resources that are available to the client ...

You get links that represent resources. To retrieve specific resources you should call corresponding URL. Your response for User 1 means that if you want to get Skills of User 1 you should call URL "http://localhost:8085/users/1/skills".

It is easier to understand it if you imagine that you have an HTML page that displays properties of User 1. This page does not directly display Skills, instead this page contains a link to Skills page. Only if a user clicks on this link the Skills page will be loaded.

It is important that you understand [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) well.

Of course there can be cases when HATEOAS is not the best choice. But here we are not discussing HATEOAS, but explaining what is the idea behind this implementation of Spring. This approach can really be helpful in many cases. When you have 2 entities with 1-2 attributes, you may consider such approach as overkill. But if you have 30 - 50 entities, each with 3 - 5 relations, each relation containing 50 - 100 other entities, it can be quite hard to deal with such data model. And HATEOAS can make it much easier. With this approach you are just *navigating* these relations: load one entity, select needed relation, load entities on this relation, select needed entity, in this entity select needed relation, load this relation, or navigate back to its parent entity via parent relation, etc.

Comment: But by clicking on `http://localhost:8085/users/1/skills` link I get `skills[]`. Any reason to that?